# Excel 2016 filter/comparing data for extraction

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two workbooks. Book1 is an exported list from an Admin portal for MS licensing which contains about 100 users(rows) with data across several columns. One column has company emails.

Book2 is an export of users from Hyena that contains data, including emails, also across several columns with various headings such as Title, Dept, Location etc. This list has about 30K users(rows).

What I need to do is identify the 100 users from the first workbook within the 30K of the second workbook so I can then extract the info in their rows and transfer it back to the original workbook.

Since both books have user emails, I was trying to copy the email column from book1 to a column in book2 to use as a comparison, since the emails will be written the same. I've tried a few formulas but so far can't get it to do what I want. Also, the column in book2 that contains the emails has alot of blank spaces due to not all user accounts having an associated email. Not sure if that's causing a problem either.

EDIT: I added and example. The headings are the same in the originals. I can't remove spaces in book2 as it'll break the rows of info I need.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMrkw.png)

Comment: Can you not provide a small sample of your data from the spreadsheets, etc. and then give example of this is what I have, this is what I get,  and this is what I want it to be instead? Simply add a small sample of the data and clarify some of this as such. Just [edit] to begin this simple process of adding this detail.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it, is to copy the book1 email addresses into a new sheet in book2 and then filter book2 based on book1 email addresses. If you have some formatting issues (blank spaces etc.) you should clean these up first.

To filter based on a list, go to the data ribbon in excel and click on 'advanced filter' under 'Sort & Filter'. Then define your book2 email addresses as **list range** and book1 email addresses as your **criteria**.

Comment: I tried this, but I can't remove the spaces. End resulted in a blank sheet, with only the headings. List Range: Hyena_Export2!$C$1:$C$30500, Criteria Range: $K$1:$K$114

Comment: Maybe try to split the field somehow, or use =trim() to get rid of the white spaces. 
Edit: this is for trailing and leading spaces. For spaces inside a string you could use =SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","").